# jsf iterate over hashmap

Tags: jsf, hashmap, iteration

question about iterating over list of hashmap has been asked many times and tried the same solution but its not working. 
I'm trying to display values inside hasmap but its not working on jsf page(I'm using jsf2.1). When I tried to iterate in java it displays all values so I know map is not empty.
This is what I tried with help of @BalusC solution

```
<ui:repeat var="aClip" value="#{manageClipModel.clipList}">
<ui:repeat value="#{aClip.revisions}" var="revs">
rev id <h:outputText value="#{revs.revId}"/>  //dispalys value  
map len #{fn:length(revs.metadataMap.entry)}  //displays right size of map                                   
  <c:forEach items="#{revs.metadataMap.entry}" var="entry">
      key <h:outputText value="#{abc.key}"/> //does  not iterate this loop
   </c:forEach>
</ui:repeat>
```

In java values are displayed properly

```
      for (Clip aClip : clipList) {
        System.out.println("comment " + aClip.getComment() + " clip id " + Clip.getClipId());

        List<Revision> revs = aClip.getRevisions();
        System.out.println("rev size"+revs.size());
        if (revs != null && !revs.isEmpty()) {
            for (Revision aRev : revs) {
                System.out.println("metadata map size " + aRev.getMetadataMap().getEntry().size());                    
                Iterator itr = aRev.getMetadataMap().getEntry().listIterator();
                while (itr.hasNext()) {
                    Revision.MetadataMap.Entry entry = (Revision.MetadataMap.Entry) itr.next();
                    System.out.println("key " + entry.getKey());
                    System.out.println("value " + entry.getValue().getValues().toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone point what is wrong I'm doing?

Comment: Instead of adding `solved` and the solution to the question, you can post an answer and accept it.

Comment: I did add the solution to the question. if you see the post its edited, couldnt figure out how to post an answer to own post

Comment: See the button `Answer Your Question` below?

Answer (score 0):

(Question answered by the OP in a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> Solved I was missing one step which was `listIterator` loop from Java code.

```
<ui:repeat value="#{aClip.revisions}" var="revs">                              
   <ui:repeat value="#{revs.metadataMap.entry}" var="entryLst">//was missing this loop
      <ui:repeat value="#{entryLst}" var="entry">
        <ui:repeat value="#{entry.value}" var="metaVal">
            changedFromPrevious - <h:outputText value="#metaVal.changedFromPrevious}"/>
             key - <h:outputText value="#{metaVal.key}"/>    
             <ui:repeat value="#{metaVal.values}" var="aValue">
                    <h:outputText value="#{aValue}"/>    
             </ui:repeat>
           </ui:repeat>
          </ui:repeat>
        </ui:repeat>
```